# how to click in this element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to select this element and i have a lot of it in consol

```
<div class="oajrlxb2 gs1a9yip g5ia77u1 mtkw9kbi tlpljxtp qensuy8j ppp5ayq2 goun2846 ccm00jje s44p3ltw mk2mc5f4 rt8b4zig n8ej3o3l agehan2d sk4xxmp2 rq0escxv nhd2j8a9 j83agx80 mg4g778l btwxx1t3 pfnyh3mw p7hjln8o kvgmc6g5 cxmmr5t8 oygrvhab hcukyx3x tgvbjcpo hpfvmrgz jb3vyjys rz4wbd8a qt6c0cv9 a8nywdso l9j0dhe7 i1ao9s8h esuyzwwr f1sip0of du4w35lb lzcic4wl n00je7tq arfg74bv qs9ysxi8 k77z8yql abiwlrkh p8dawk7l" role="button" tabindex="0">683px; background-size: auto; width: 20px; height: 20px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: inline-block;"></i></div></div></div>
```

Comment: click on the first div in a collection of div

Comment: Can you share bit more outerHTML ?

Comment: How can you write the code

Comment: This is the all element
https://prnt.sc/218q14k

Answer (score 0):

You could find the element by its `class` like the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("oajrlxb2 gs1a9yip g5ia77u1 mtkw9kbi tlpljxtp qensuy8j ppp5ayq2 goun2846 ccm00jje s44p3ltw mk2mc5f4 rt8b4zig n8ej3o3l agehan2d sk4xxmp2 rq0escxv nhd2j8a9 j83agx80 mg4g778l btwxx1t3 pfnyh3mw p7hjln8o kvgmc6g5 cxmmr5t8 oygrvhab hcukyx3x tgvbjcpo hpfvmrgz jb3vyjys rz4wbd8a qt6c0cv9 a8nywdso l9j0dhe7 i1ao9s8h esuyzwwr f1sip0of du4w35lb lzcic4wl n00je7tq arfg74bv qs9ysxi8 k77z8yql abiwlrkh p8dawk7l").click()
```

But because the class name is so long you could try the `contains` with `xpath`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'oajrlxb2 gs1a9yip g5ia77u1 mtkw9kbi tlpljxtp qensuy8j ppp5ayq2')]").click()
```

Or find the element by its `role`, in this case, `role='button'`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@role='button']").click()
```